# CURL request headers seemingly not being set in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a CURL request and I'm having some interesting issues. Even though I'm seemingly setting the headers correctly, using curl_getinfo() after the execution shows that there's no headers. The request times out on my server, and when using the command line version of curl. On my desktop, I can send the same curl request and get a result. I'm assuming it's a firewall issue, since accessing the site through a browser gives a Bitdefender mismatched certificate warning. Any ideas?

```
public static function GetCurlHandler() {
    // Initialize CURL handler
    $curlHandler = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, PATH_TO_COOKIES_FILE );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, PATH_TO_COOKIES_FILE );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_CAINFO, PATH_TO_CACERT_PEM );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate' );
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 ); // default to older CURL version for supporting older programs

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade: h2'; // tell the server to use https2 if available
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt( $curlHandler, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );
    return $curlHandler;
}
  
  
static function GetCapabilities($urlBase = 'https://madison.rexburg.org/mrgis/rest/services/Downtown/BLDGFootprint/FeatureServer/0',$recursionDepth=1)
{   $url = $urlBase.'?f=json';
    Log::info("Getting capabilities for $url");

    $curlHandler = self::GetCurlHandler();
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $curlResponse = curl_exec( $curlHandler );

    $info = curl_getinfo( $curlHandler );
    print_r( $info );
    print_r( curl_error( $curlHandler ) );
    var_dump( $curlResponse );
    echo "\n";
    curl_close( $curlHandler );

    $jsonObject = json_decode($curlResponse);
    if( empty( $jsonObject ) ) {
        \log::error( 'empty response from server, retrying with other HTTP version...' );
        $curlHandler = self::GetCurlHandler();
        curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE);
        $curlResponse = curl_exec( $curlHandler );
        print_r( curl_error( $curlHandler ) );
        curl_close( $curlHandler );
        $jsonObject = json_decode( $curlResponse );
        if( empty( $jsonObject ) ) {
            var_dump( $curlResponse );
            throw new \Exception( 'empty response from server' ); // This is where I end up
        }
```

**Resulting Text:**

```
 ‣ 00:00:00.049 [INFO] Getting capabilities for https://madison.rexburg.org/mrgis/rest/services/Downtown/BLDGFootprint/FeatureServer/0?f=json
Array
(
    [url] => https://madison.rexburg.org/mrgis/rest/services/Downtown/BLDGFootprint/FeatureServer/0?f=json
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 21.220237
    [namelookup_time] => 0.002064
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [http_version] => 0
    [protocol] => 0
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => 
    [appconnect_time_us] => 0
    [connect_time_us] => 0
    [namelookup_time_us] => 2064
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 0
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 0
    [total_time_us] => 21220237
)
Failed to connect to madison.rexburg.org port 443: Timed outbool(false)

  ‣ 00:00:21.281 [ERROR] empty response from server, retrying with other HTTP version...
Failed to connect to madison.rexburg.org port 443: Timed outbool(false)
  ‣ 00:00:42.513 [ERROR] Exception: empty response from server
```

**Command Line Equivalent:**

```
curl -L "https://madison.rexburg.org/mrgis/rest/services/Downtown/BLDGFootprint/FeatureServer/0?f=json" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Upgrade: h2" --output - --verbose --http1.1
```

**Server Information:**

- PHP 7.4.33
- Windows NT 10.0 build 17763 (Windows Server 2016) AMD64
- Running in a Google Cloud Services VM
- Compiled in  Visual C++ 2017
- Apache 2.0 Handler
- Configure command:   cscript /nologo /e:jscript configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
- CURL version 8.0.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.0.1

**Relevant Infrastructure Info:**
I'm just a junior dev, so I'm going to try my best to provide some network and general infrastructure information.

- Default route:

  {
  "creationTimestamp": "2017-12-08T13:34:07.643-08:00",
  "description": "Default route to the Internet.",
  "destRange": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "id": "4955173435988163488",
  "kind": "compute#route",
  "name": "default-route-b06db13fc2a2a102",
  "network": "projects/our-server/global/networks/default",
  "nextHopGateway": "projects/our-server/global/gateways/default-internet-gateway",
  "priority": 1000,
  "selfLink": "projects/our-server/global/routes/default-route-b06db13fc2a2a102"
  }
- VPC Firewall information: HTTP traffic off, HTTPS traffic on, nothing blocking egress from relevant port

Comment: "The request times out on my server" - That's all you needed to say - the rest is irrelevant. Although a [minimal verifiable example][1] along with the actual error message would have been helpful. We can't tell you how to investigate/resolve an issue on an infrastructure you've told us nothing about.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @symcbean I added a section with server information, if there's any other relevant information you think I should add just let me know.

Comment: I didn't ask about the server - I asked about the infrastructure it runs on. The host OS, the scurity controls therein, the network, the default route, the DNS provisioning, the active network components between the host and the public internet. Since this is a hosted VM you only see some of these - but should be more than enough to identify the cause.

Comment: you should not use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to set GET or POST or HEAD, for these there are special option, but GET is default so you don't need to set it at all.

Comment: also you are checking the result of `json_decode` which could return NULL for invalid JSON string which is therefore considered empty even though the response isn't.

Comment: @Kazz The var_dump for the response is just a boolean false, so it's failing before it can return anything, but I'll remember that for the future!

Comment: @symcbean just type `[mcve]`, no need for bracket citations. (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments)

Comment: the absence of `request_header` is expected when the request fail, the test/check you are doing, does not prove that the headers are not present in request. can't see anything wrong with your code, so i believe that the host where you run the script is blacklisted at the server you are trying to connect to. firewall block on the way is usually done as rejection so you know about that, while the server use drop instead to not notify about the blockage. try to run this script at another host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the script can't connect to the intended target. The most likely reasons for this are:

1. the host cannot resolve the DNS name correctly
2. there is no connectivity out to the internet

Test these in isolation:

```
<?php

error_rporting(E_ALL);

$ip=gethostbyname('madison.rexburg.org');

print "$ip=gethostbyname('madison.rexburg.org')<br />";

flush();

$errcode=0;
$errmsg='notrun';

$conn=fsockopen("192.225.178.54", 443, $errcode, $errmsg, 10);

if (!$conn) {
   print "error ($errcode): $errmsg";
} else {
   print "connectivity is good";
}
?>
```

Comment: It returns "error (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond". Since the server can connect to other addresses, I'm guessing my server has been blocked from accessing their site

Comment: Gave the company a call and it turns out they recently started working with a different IT company that put new firewall rules in place, so we were accidentally getting blocked. Thanks for the useful information, I really appreciate it!